# setTextviewText() method of RemoteView class not setting any text

Tags: android, gridview, widget

I am using GridView in app widget.I want to show images and a text below each image in the widget.Images(app icons) are getting displayed; but the text is not getting displayed.I am using setTextViewText() to set the text.

getViewAt() method of WidgetViewsFactory.java class:

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position)  {

    RemoteViews row = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_list_row);

    ApplicationInfo data = null;
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationReceiverIntent.class);
    PendingIntent pendingLaunchIntent;
    try {
        packageName = appsPackageNameList.get(position).split(";;");
        data = packageManager
                .getApplicationInfo(packageName[0], 0);

        if (null != data) {
            Bitmap icon = CommonCode.getBitmapFromIcon(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
            row.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.img_widget, icon);
            Log.e("count", packageName[1]);
            row.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_notification_count, packageName[1]); //setting text
        }

    } catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return (row);
}
```

I am printing the text(array value)which is giving me proper values.
So what should I do to set the text in my widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer after digging into my code.
The default color of TextView is white in the widget so I simply changed
 my Text color to black from xml and it worked!!

Answer (score -1):

At last for adding the text, you have to use

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, row);
```